# Qt - using Widgets and QLabel to display multiple images

Tags: image, qt4

So currently I am able to display images via URL's using QLabel, QNetworkManager and QPixmap. And then to display the image I use something like label->show(). Essentially I follow the same steps as in the pseudocode in this link:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/7010

Now I am still somewhat new to Qt and am having difficulty extending this. What I want to do is be able to display multiple images from different URL's into essentially the same container. So basically I want to see two images in the same container/window. These images are specified by their width, height, x position and y position in the main window/container. I know that I should use widgets but I am not sure what exactly should I use? QFrame? QHBLayout? QScrollArea? etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many QLabels inside a Layout to get the effect you want. The way you want to lay it out is up to you, and there's more than one layout manager. There's things like the grid layout, the box layout, etc. Have a look here for layouts. You can look at it in this simplified way:
One window has a layout and a layout has many items in it.
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html

In reality widgets can contain many other widgets. To position them properly, you use the layout.